# MS access code gives different results each execution against same data

Tags: ms-access-2013

i'm in the process of roughing out a proof of concept for desktop software i'd like to develop. I'm using Access 2013.

The following code is supposed to analyse records in one table ('tblRestructures') and depending on the analysis it should then populate records in another table ('tblInScopeRestructures'). The sample data in tblRestructures is set up such that the code should cause there to be records with field(Gen) with values 1 to 6 inclusive. Sometimes the code does succeed in populating tblInScopeRestructures as expected but other times the code ends early (ie conditions for ending various loops are met). Despite a lot of time spent trying to identify the cause of the variability and looking for similar questions here, I am still none the wiser.

Any help here is gratefully received. And I apologise up front for my ugly code - I am not experienced and at this stage I am just trying to speed through a proof of concept.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function NbrOfShares3(strCode As String, dteDate As Date) As Single
Dim i As Integer
Dim strPrevCode1 As String
Dim adConn As ADODB.Connection
Set adConn = New ADODB.Connection
adConn.Open CurrentProject.Connection
Dim adrsa As ADODB.Recordset
Set adrsa = New ADODB.Recordset
adConn.Execute "DELETE * from tblInScopeRestructures"
adrsa.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
adrsa.CursorType = adOpenStatic
' Identify all gen 1 (Code1 = CODE) restructures up to dteDate and put in a temp table
adrsa.Open "SELECT tblRestructure.Code1, tblRestructure.Code2, tblRestructure.RecDate " & _
"FROM tblRestructure " & _
"WHERE (((tblRestructure.Code1)='" & strCode & "'))  AND (((tblRestructure.RecDate)<=#" & Format(dteDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#));"
If adrsa.RecordCount <> 0 Then
    adrsa.MoveFirst
    Do While Not adrsa.EOF
       adConn.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblInScopeRestructures(Code1,Code2,RecDate,Gen) VALUES ('" & adrsa.Fields("Code1") & "','" & adrsa.Fields("Code2") & _
       "',#" & Format(adrsa.Fields("RecDate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#," & 1 & ")")
       adrsa.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
i = 0
'Identify all code1 in
Dim adrsb As ADODB.Recordset
Set adrsb = New ADODB.Recordset
adrsb.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
Do
    i = i + 1
    If adrsb.State = 1 Then
        adrsb.Close
    End If
    adrsb.CursorType = adOpenStatic

    adrsb.Open "SELECT tblInScopeRestructures.Code1, tblInScopeRestructures.Gen " & _
    "FROM tblInScopeRestructures " & _
    "GROUP BY tblInScopeRestructures.Code1, tblInScopeRestructures.Gen " & _
    "HAVING (((tblInScopeRestructures.Gen)=" & i & "));"
    Dim adrsc As ADODB.Recordset
    Set adrsc = New ADODB.Recordset
    adrsc.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    adrsc.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    If Not adrsb.EOF Then
        adrsb.MoveLast
        adrsb.MoveFirst
    End If
    If adrsb.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        adrsb.MoveFirst
        strPrevCode1 = adrsb.Fields("Code1")
        Do While Not adrsb.EOF
            If adrsc.State = 1 Then
                adrsc.Close
            End If
            adrsc.CursorType = adOpenStatic
            adrsc.Open "SELECT tblRestructure.Code1, tblRestructure.Code2, tblRestructure.RecDate " & _
            "FROM tblRestructure " & _
            "WHERE (((tblRestructure.Code2)='" & strPrevCode1 & "'));"
            If adrsc.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            adrsc.MoveFirst
            Do While Not adrsc.EOF
           adConn.Execute ("INSERT INTO tblInScopeRestructures(Code1,Code2,RecDate,Gen) VALUES ('" & adrsc.Fields("Code1") & "','" & adrsc.Fields("Code2") & _
           "',#" & Format(adrsc.Fields("RecDate"), "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#," & i + 1 & ")")
           adrsc.MoveNext
           Loop
           End If
          adrsb.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
Loop While adrsb.RecordCount <> 0
  Debug.Print "finished"
End Function
```

Comment: Please read: [mcve] - few people will want to read through all that uncommented code. Try to reduce it to the relevant parts. -- Also recommended: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Hi - after much time spent debugging I think my issue is with the apparent slow execution of the INSERT INTO command. If I step through in debug slowly, the code works as expected. However if I run or step through quickly the adrsb recordset ends up with a zero recordcount earlier than expected because the earlier appended records in tblInScopeRestructures are not found by the select query. This frustrates me because I thought the INSERT INTO command would be completed before the next line of code is actioned. Any light on this gratefully received.